# Is there a way to make a dynamic text area in react

Tags: reactjs, textarea, react-bootstrap, form-control

I am playing around with React Components and I came across this website that goes over different ways to use Form Control with bootstrap styling. I want to create a text area that dynamically changes in size when user presses enter, but with the following exercise a scroll bar gets added. I could just change the number of rows, but is there a way to make the text field change in size every-time a user creates a new line

```
  <Form.Group controlId="exampleForm.ControlTextarea1">
    <Form.Label>Example textarea</Form.Label>
    <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={1} />
  </Form.Group>
```

[React bootstrap examples](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-controls)

Thank you for your time and answer

Comment: This isn't really a React question. Check out this article: https://gomakethings.com/automatically-expand-a-textarea-as-the-user-types-using-vanilla-javascript/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package would have the behavior you are looking for: [react-textarea-autosize](https://github.com/Andarist/react-textarea-autosize)

For making it bootstrap-like, I'd suggest adding a bootstrap css className to this component ([more info](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/overview/#overview)):

```
<TextareaAutosize className="form-control" />
```